# Select Query to get data that matches and do not matches the where condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

- If there is a total of 1000 records in a table
- I need to get total of 500 rows that matches multiple conditions
- out of N conditions one Condition(A) is like an optional condition
- if there are only 50 records that matches all the N conditions and 600 
    records that matches all N-1 conditions (except A)
- then i need to get an composite of 50 + (450 records out of 600 records) as 
    a 500 records from SQL
- Usage of LEFT JOIN is not intended as we have a table with high volume of 
    data

### Example:

[image]

- From the above table i need to get 4 Id's that matches Course B.Tech and age above 25
- The course table is an optional Condition so i need to get ids 1,2,3,5,6 as an result
- From this 6 rows i need to get 5 records in which  i cannot elimnate id 5 as it matches all conditions instead i can eliminate any one record apart from this as other records matches only one condition

Comment: Any sample data and expected output will be required also what you have tried to get the answer quickly.

Comment: @SurajKumar had added an sample data

Answer (score 2):

You add this condition to a case expression in the `order by` clause and thus make sure you get these records first:

```
SELECT    TOP 500 *
FROM      mytable
WHERE     /* conditions */
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN /* optional condition */ THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query using union `clause`

```
create table #temp (id int, Age int, Course varchar(20))
insert into #temp values (1, 25, 'BE'),(2, 30, 'BE'),(3, 40, 'BE'),(4, 22, 'BE'),(5, 25, 'B. Tech'),(6, 27, 'BE')

select Top 4 * from #temp
where age >= 25 
union
select * from #temp
where (Course is null or Course = 'B. Tech')
union
select * from #temp
where age >= 25 OR (Course is null or Course = 'B. Tech')
```

The output is as shown below

```
id  Age Course
1   25  BE
2   30  BE
3   40  BE
5   25  B. Tech
6   27  BE
```

You can find the live domo here- [**Demo Data Matches**](https://rextester.com/HLJUYO66720)